# Download specific rows of data from a file from a website using Python and Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, wget

I wish to download a file (https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv) from the internet using Python and Google Cloud.

Currently, I have this code.

```
import os
import wget

from google.cloud import storage

url = os.environ['URL']
bucket_name = os.environ['BUCKET'] #without gs://
file_name = os.environ['FILE_NAME']

cf_path = '/tmp/{}'.format(file_name)

def import_file(event, context):

    # set storage client
    client = storage.Client()

    # get bucket
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    # download the file to Cloud Function's tmp directory
    wget.download(url, cf_path)

    # set Blob
    blob = storage.Blob(file_name, bucket)
 
    # upload the file to GCS
    blob.upload_from_filename(cf_path)

    print("""This Function was triggered by messageId {} published at {}""".format(context.event_id, context.timestamp))
```

While this code works beautifully, the Covid19 data updates on a daily with addition of new date (So if I access the file on 3/7, it would include data till 3/6) . **Instead of re-writing the whole file again, I wish to only extract the newly updated rows into google storage for every time the function is run on scheduled as opposed to overwriting the file that was already saved.**

I fairly weal in programming and would appreciate the help.

While the file is in csv format, there's also a JSON link (https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json) if it would make it easier to code.

I can figure out the portion on storing it to Cloud Storage but **requires help on the code to extract the most updated rows/data in more specifically**.

Comment: Cloud Storage stores blobs. Any formatting or structure is implemented in your logic. Cloud Storage knows nothing about new data, old data, CSVs, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for your reply. The file would essentially be imported from cloud storage to biq query. If I wish to only import the latest rows of data into biq query (instead of overwriting the data saved in biq query) given the download from cloud storage, is there any way I can do this? I would appreciate your take on how you would do it.

Comment: For new data create a new blob. Then you can load that blob into BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The usual best practice is to load data everyday in BigQuery and to partition per [ingestion date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#ingestion_time).

Then, you can run a query (or create a view) to select only the most recent data of type (use the [partition over](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#syntax) syntax) (deduplicate)